# How new objectc can be created in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, types, instantiation

What does this syntax mean?

```
date aaa(2011,7,1);
```

Instead of aaa I can use whatever I want (for example `bbb` or `ccc`). It looks like I create a new object called `aaa` and belonging to the class `date`. But us far as I known I need to use the `new` keyword to create a new object.

Comment: please read at least one c++ tutorial for beginners. It is hard to learn a language just by asking questions.

Comment: This is very long to explain. I think you should grab a book about C++ and read the chapter about object creation.

Comment: What the others said. Learn yourself some C++ before asking C++ questions. This is *way too basic* ("How do I move the turtle in Logo?" anyone?). Have a look at [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Repeat one hundred times: "C++ is not Java." Then get a book about C++. Not Java.

Comment: @Pete Becker, I do not use Java. I saw `new` in the C++ examples.

Comment: Fair enough. It's a common misunderstanding from Java programmers when they grow up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means "create an instance of `data` called `aaa` by calling a constructor of `date` which takes three integer parameters (or parameters that can be implicitly constructed from int)".

In C++, you **do not** need the `new` keyword to create an object. `new` instantiates an object in dynamic storage and returns you a pointer to it. Amongst other things, it means that you (or someone, somewhere) has to take responsibility for deleting the object at some point.

Answer (score 5):

```
int x;
```

I'm sure you understand that this defines an `int` object named `x`. Did you use `new`? How about if we add copy-initialization:

```
int x = 5;
```

This defines an `int` object named `x` and initialises it to 5. The same result can be achieved with direct-initialization:

```
int x(5);
```

So what about:

```
data aaa(2011,7,1);
```

This is precisely like the above syntax. We're creating an object of type `data` called `aaa`, just this time we're passing three arguments to its constructor.

The thing that all of these definitions have in common is that they create an object of a certain type with *automatic storage duration*. This means that the objects will be destroyed at the end of their scope.

Now consider the following line:

```
int* p = new int(5);
```

This creates *two* objects. The first is an `int*` called `p`. That `int*` has automatic storage duration, just as above, and will be destroyed at the end of its scope. We then initialise that object with the pointer returned by `new int(5)`. This new-expression creates an `int` object, initialized to 5, with *dynamic storage duration*. That means that it is not destroyed automatically at the end of its scope, but needs to be `delete`d.

So, in short, these are two different ways to create objects that give them different storage durations.

Comment: `int x(5);` does initialize object to 5. `int x = 5;` does not. It creates and object and assigns 5 to it. There is a semantic difference between, calling a constructor `T()` and `operator=(int)` versus `T(int)`. OP asked question on such an elementary level I think it's best to keep answers super strict. Or am I wrong and `T(int)` would be called ?

Comment: @luk32 `int x = 5;` does not do any assignment - it is *copy-initialization* and has precisely the same effect (in this case) as doing `int x(5);`. No `operator=` is used here.

Comment: Ok my bad then. Sorry. I though those are semantically different.

Comment: Uhm. OK, they ARE semantically different. I know that in case of `int` the result is the same. But it can be very different and copy-/direct- initializations are not interchangeable in general case. That was my original point, although I was wrong what actually happens. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @luk32 if the types on the LHS and RHS are different, then they are semantically different. There still is no assignment involved though.

Answer (score 1):

In some languages *similar* to C++ you might need `new` to create objects, for example Java. However in C++ you don't *have* to.

In C++ you use `new` to create a new object *on the heap*, for example if you need to create one dynamically during runtime. If you declare a variable such as the one in your example, it will be created *on the stack* if it's a local variable inside a function. Those objects are only available as long as their scope lasts.

Answer (score 0):

The new operator instantiate an object in *heap* memory and that object exist until delete is called. In your example the object is instantiated in the *stack* and exist only in the scope (until the next `}`).